# Limit string to 2 numbers after comma and only ONE comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this script below to allow only numbers and comma on a input text.

```
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9,]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}

<input type="text" name="price" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
```

How can I modify this code to allow only **one comma** and after the comma allow only **two** numbers? I wouldn't like to use jQuery to solve this issue.

```
EXAMPLE:
1234,56 (stop)
1,23 (stop)
123,45 (stop)
1234567,89 (stop)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your validation function will only check the current key, but you need to check the value of the input element. You can use a pattern like this:

```
/^\d+(,\d{0,2})?$/
```

This will match any string consisting of a sequence of digits, optionally followed by a comma and up to two digits.

Your entire validation function would look a bit like this:

```
function validate(evt, ele) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var value = ele.value + key;
  var regex = /^\d+(,\d{0,2})?$/;
  if( !regex.test(value) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}

<input type="text" name="price" onkeypress='validate(event, this)'>
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/362D4/2/)

If also you want to ensure that the user types 2 digits after the comma, you'd have to do a second validation on the final value before they submit the form using a pattern like this:

```
/^\d+,\d{2}$/
```

This will match any string consisting of a sequence of digits, followed by a comma, followed by exactly two digits. The start (`^`) and stop (`$`) anchors ensure that there are no other characters allowed before or after the matched string.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex replace, like this:

```
var x = "123,456,7890";
var a = x.replace(/(,[0-9]{2})([0-9,]*)/, "$1");
```