# Validate input with only number and decimal after dot

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, validation

I'm trying to make a validation that must accept the decimal numbers with up to 3 fields. The comma can only appear if you have at least one number entered

`Allow:`

100,000
1,0
1
1,00

---

`Doesn't Allow:`

,00
,150
,0
100 100

I tried it (I'm using `React` to get the input value):

```
var code = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
if (code !== 46 && (code < 48 || code > 57)) {
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

So far, I have managed to limit only fields and the point. But, it still allows `.000` and is not limited to 3 decimal places.

How can I do this?

-------------- UPDATE SOLUTION --------------

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571121/5634596) that solve my problem. Thank you so much for your help guys

Comment: Validate the whole value, don't validate individual keypresses. What happens if the user moves the cursor between keypresses?

Comment: Your solution is not a regular expression. You should ask for one specifically or remove the [regex] tag.

Comment: What do you mean by a decimal number with up to 3 fields? Is it 3 digits after the comma or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your question well (I can update my solution based on your input) but I think you need a regular expression to match your overall value, not the individual inputs:

```
function is_valid(value) {
  var exp = /^\d+(,*\d+)?$/;
  return exp.test(value)
}

tests = ["100,000", "1,0", "1", "1,00", ",00", ",150", ",0", "100 100"]

for(var i=0; i<tests.length; i++) {
  console.log(tests[i], is_valid(tests[i]))
}
```

Comment: I found a solution (I updated my question). Thank you so much for your help!